# adoquery Execute multiple sql can't rollback

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, sql-server-2000

`qryTemp2` is a `TADOQuery`

1. if code like this, rollback will be called and no inserts will be made, but I think, if the database is on the cloud, this will take more time.

   ```
   qryTemp2.Connection.BeginTrans;
   try
       qryTemp2.Close;
       qryTemp2.SQL.Text := 'insert sql1，this sql is good';
       qryTemp2.ExecSQL;

       qryTemp2.Close;
       qryTemp2.SQL.Text :='insert sql2,this sql will raise a exception';
       qryTemp2.ExecSQL;

       qryTemp2.Connection.CommitTrans;
   except
       on e:Exception do
       begin
           qryTemp2.Connection.RollbackTrans;
           Exit;
       end;
   end;
   ```
2. If I write like this, sql1 will be inserted and rollback is not called.
   Can I do something to make rollback called?

   ```
   qryTemp2.Connection.BeginTrans;
   try
       qryTemp2.Close;
       qryTemp2.SQL.Text :=    'insert sql1，this sql is good'+#13#10+
                               'insert sql2,this sql will raise a exception';
       qryTemp2.ExecSQL;

       qryTemp2.Connection.CommitTrans;
   except
       on e:Exception do
       begin
           qryTemp2.Connection.RollbackTrans;
           Exit;
       end;
   end;
   ```

thank you!

Comment: btw: i want it works both on sql2000 and sql2008,thanks

Comment: Rollback will perform if execution within the `try..except` block raises an exception. Transaction won't be committed if that happens. What else can we say?

Comment: but sql2000 not support try..except,sad@Victoria

Comment: But Delphi does :) You seem to be missing just `;` between your commands. But in your case try to prefer `qryTemp2.SQL.Add('<your SQL command>');` per command instead.

Comment: thans for your answer,but if i add a ; bewteen sql1 and sql2, qryTemp2.SQL.Text := 'insert sql1，this sql is good;'+#13#10+
      'insert sql2,this sql will raise a exception'; it still not works.roll back is not called.@Victoria

Comment: Exception handling is known to work. In your case, any exception that is raised by ADO will execute what's inside the exception block. I cannot see any problem here. Your transaction block is correct. I cannot speak for that `#13#10` thing however. ADO is far behind me but I would prefer to separate commands by using `qryTemp2.SQL.Add()` at least. It's weird to me, at least to say (I'd say to my clients they need to update).

Comment: i change the code to qryTemp2.SQL.Add('sql1...');qryTemp2.SQL.Add('sql2...');still not works.but thank you for your help @Victoria.maybe i can only use the code1 to execute sql sperate,Weird 233

Comment: Sorry, I'm no good at ADO :( It's weird what you describe, but honestly, the best I would suggest to such clients is, update to SQL Server which is not 17 years old. Windows 2k support e.g. ended 7 years ago.

Comment: Can you check `DECLARE @XACT_ABORT VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (16384 & @@OPTIONS) = 16384 ) SET @XACT_ABORT = 'ON';  
SELECT @XACT_ABORT AS XACT_ABORT;`? If it is `OFF` in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. Try to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON; ` before transaction starts.

Comment: @gofr1 thank you.it works after i change code to qryTemp2.SQL.Text :=    'SET XACT_ABORT ON'+#13#10+'insert sql1，this sql is good'+#13#10+
                            'insert sql2,this sql will raise a exception';